# How to convert HTML to pdf and download in external storage (Android&IOS) react-native?

Tags: react-native, html-to-pdf

I am working on react-native latest version. I am try a convent html to **pdf** using this library [react-native-html-to-pdf](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf). But getting lots of error after installation.

**Errors:**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.spongycastle.crypto.PasswordConverter found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and core-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.crypto.PasswordConverter$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and core-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.crypto.PasswordConverter$2 found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and core-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.crypto.PasswordConverter$3 found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and core-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.crypto.util.DERMacData found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and core-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.crypto.util.DERMacData$Type found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and core-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.RSA found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.RSA$Mappings found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi$SHA256withRSA found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.AES found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.AES$AlgParamsGCM found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.AES$ECB found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.AES$ECB$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
Duplicate class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.AES$Mappings found in modules classes.jar (com.nds.threeds:threedssdk-release:1.1.17) and prov-1.58.0.0.jar (com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0)
```

**Requirement:** 
Convert the html into pdf and store in external storage of phone. (Android&ISO)

Please tell me how to do this? And how I can save pdf on specified location?